# Changing the background color of xml shape in android

Tags: android, xml, drawable, shapes

I have a shape I've created in an xml file as follows

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/shape">
<padding
    android:left="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp" />
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

In my app I have 10-14 views with the above shape as the background however for each view I need to have a seperate shape file just to change the colors of each. Is there some way that I can use just one file and change the background color when I create a new shape? and is it possible to do it directly in the xml file when I create the shape views?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?